# C++ template for both passing a vector by constant reference and raw pointer

Tags: c++, templates, vector

(Trivial template specialization isn't a silver bullet in this case!)

I am working on some image processing code and am interfacing with some Cython. To interact with Cython I need to pass a raw pointer to a function to avoid copy overhead. I realized that it would be nice to work with boolean images to save memory in some cases, so ideally I could change the declaration from:

```
template <typename T>
uint32_t* connected_components(
    T* in_labels, ...
)
```

To this:

```
template <typename T>
uint32_t* connected_components(
    const std::vector<T> &in_labels, ...
)
```

However, to support the bit packed case, I can't just cast the vector's container to a pointer in a specialization, I need to preserve the vector class semantics.

Is there a way to write this template such that it will declare `in_labels` as both a pointer and a vector? I can just copy the code, but I'd rather not as it is a rather complex implementation of a fast algorithm.

Edit: I suppose a giant macro would work... but it's ugly.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not looking to allow Cython to access the bit packed vector version, I just want to make it available in the C++ interface.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to do. My suggestion: If you had to hand code everything, what would that look like? If you can post that, I am sure somebody will be able to help you with DRY.

Comment: if you're looking to use `T*` the same way as `vector<bool>` then your best bet is to access the data via *iterators*

Comment: Notice that the packing of `std::vector<bool>` is **optional**, if you expect a (dynamic) bitset, you cannot rely portably on `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: `template <typename TIter> uint32_t connected_components(TIter it_begin, TIter it_end)` will accept both pointers and `begin()` and `end()` vector iterators. Then iterate with `for (auto it = it_begin; it != it_end; ++it)` to loop, and `*it` to access the value.

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into iterators. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I figured out a simpler solution. I'll just make the vector specialization contain the algorithmic code and cast the raw pointer to a vector in its own specialization. I'll then let Cython interact with the pointer specialization while other uses can default to the vector specialization.

```
template <typename T>
uint32_t* connected_components3d_26(
    const std::vector<T> &in_labels, 
    const int64_t sx, const int64_t sy, const int64_t sz,
    int64_t max_labels, uint32_t *out_labels = NULL
  ) {

    // algorithm goes here
}


template <typename T>
uint32_t* connected_components3d_26(
    T* in_labels, 
    const int64_t sx, const int64_t sy, const int64_t sz,
    int64_t max_labels, uint32_t *out_labels = NULL
  ) {

  std::vector<T> vec_in_labels;
  vec_in_labels.assign(in_labels, in_labels + sx * sy * sz);

  return connected_components3d_26(
    vec_in_labels, 
    sx, sy, sz,
    max_labels, out_labels
  );
}
```

Comment: What does it mean **make the vector primary** and I don't see any cast in your code. You need to use the correct words if you want someone to be able to understand you.

Comment: I'll update the code sample to be more clear. Thank you for your feedback, the downvote is a bit harsh imo and would discourage newcomers from participating. The cast takes place where I assign the contents of the pointer to the vector container.